# Print the word that contains our pattern with the position

Tags: java, loops, search, printing, brute-force

I tried to print the word that contains our pattern with the position. I tried to use a boolean variable to check whether the text match if it matches then print but it's not working. How can I print the text with the position?

If the String pat is in the string text, then print the index which is already found and print the word that contains String pat. For example, est is inside testing, so we want to print the word testing.

Current Output

```
Pattern found at index 20
Pattern found at index 49
Pattern found at index 89
```

Want Output

```
Pattern found at index 20 in-word testing
Pattern found at index 49 in-word test
Pattern found at index 89 in-word est's
```

```
    public class FindWord {

    public static void search(String txt, String pat)
    {
        int M = pat.length();
        int N = txt.length();
        //boolean found = false;

        for (int i = 0; i <= N - M; i++) {

            int j;

            for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
                if (txt.charAt(i + j) != pat.charAt(j))
                    break;

            if (j == M)
               // found = true;
                System.out.println("Pattern found at index " + i);
//                if(found)
//                    System.out.println(txt.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String txt = "This is only for a testing input. +\n" +
                     "This is for testing, example input.+\n" +
                     "We want to find est's index and print text";
        String pat = "est";
        search(txt, pat);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to print the whole word where the substring was found. You could extract this word by searching for space characters to the left and to the right of the found string, something like the following:

```java
if (j == M) {
    // searching for a space to the left of the string
    int leftSpace = i;
    while (leftSpace > 0 && txt.charAt(leftSpace) != ' ') {
        leftSpace--;
    }

    // searching for a space to the right of the string
    int rightSpace = i + j;
    while (rightSpace < txt.length() && txt.charAt(rightSpace) != ' ') {
        rightSpace++;
    }

    // corner-case where the pattern is at the beginning of the text
    if (leftSpace != 0) {
        leftSpace++;
    }

    String word = txt.substring(leftSpace, rightSpace);

    System.out.println("Pattern found at index " + i + " in-word " + word);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lastIndexOf` and  `indexOf` to get the index of space and get the word.

```
  if (j == M){
      int s = txt.lastIndexOf(' ', i) + 1;
      int e = txt.indexOf(' ', i);
      if(e == -1) e = N;
      System.out.println("Pattern found at index " + i +" "+ txt.substring(s, e));
  }
```

Comment: Why the output for the index is not correct? The index will be greater than the actual index.

Comment: @Jack for `e` use exclusive means for calling `substring` and here is online version https://onlinegdb.com/BkcHws0eP

Comment: means exact index will be `(s, e-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't quite understand your question: do you want to print the index and the String pat if it is found in the String txt?

```
if (j == M) {
    System.out.printf("Pattern found at index %d in-word %s%n", i, pat);
}
```

In addition, you could use indexOf() method to reach the goal. Take a look at Java String: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)

Comment: Couple of ways you can do that: 1. use txt.split(" ") to split strings in the txt, and compare each string with pat, you need to have counter to track the index; 2. in the above code, add a pointer to record beginning of the word for output if match is found.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (j == M)
{
    String s = "";
    for(int k = i; txt.charAt(k) != ' ' && k >= 0; k--) s = txt.charAt(k) + s;
              
    for(int k = i + 1; txt.charAt(k) != ' ' && k < txt.length(); k++) s += txt.charAt(k);
              
    System.out.println("Pattern found at index " + i + ", " + s);
}
```

Something like this but you need to modify some detail to make it bug-free.